# The server tag is not well formed error in WhereCondition=

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I know the error is caused by the `<%# Eval("NodeID")%>` statement. When I put a literal integer, it works fine. I tried changing the outside double quotes of the WhereCondition to single quotes, and the inside quotes to double quotes, but this throws an exception.

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="subcatPreviewImages" Path= '<%# Eval("NodeAliasPath") + "/%" %>' runat="server" ClassNames="CMS.MenuItem" TransformationName="EcommerceSite.Transformations.EMCategorySmallImagePreview" OrderBy="NodeLevel, NodeOrder, NodeName" MaxRelativeLevel="4" WhereCondition="DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation='false' AND NodeParentID= <%# Eval("NodeID")%> AND NodeLevel=3" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build your string *inside* the databind tag like you did with the `NodeAliasPath` property:

```
WhereCondition='<%# "DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation='false' AND NodeParentID=" + Eval("NodeID") + " AND NodeLevel=3" %>'
```

If you are having trouble with the mixed `'` and `"` characters, you may want to move the logic that builds the expression into a function in your page:

```
public string GetWhereCondition(SomeType dataItem) {
    return "..." + dataItem.NodeID + "...";
}
```

And the your tag changes to:

```
WhereCondition="<%# GetWhereCondition(Container.DataItem) %>"
```

Disclaimer: function and type names are made up for example only -- please use appropriately named functions and replace my poorly-named ones.